# How can I force the latest container image in ACR to deploy to Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-container-registry

When I deploy to my Windows Service Fabric cluster from Azure Container Registry, the latest image is not pulled from ACR - instead the latest image available on the cluster node is just started.

I tried

- deploying as a Service Fabric application
- deploying with Compose

over VSTS and manually from the PowerShell command line.

With both options I explicitly referred to the :latest image.

Comment: do you have a connection setup to the acr on the node?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - no not explicitly; I let SF deal with bringing the images to the nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use explicit image tags, not 'latest'. This is a best practice.

Comment: this also was my solution: I changed my VSTS build & deployment so that BuildNumber goes into the image tag and in SF I only refer to the :BuildNumber tag and not :latest anymore

Comment: Did you get this working? Can you share images of what all configurations you did for this in VSTS? I am facing the same issue and not been able to resolve it.